# Converting strings in an array to dates

Tags: python, arrays, string, date, strptime

I have read an array of strings from a TXT file and saved it as an array (of over thousand values) using such a line:

```
dates = np.genfromtxt('filename.txt', delimiter=";", usecols=(0), dtype=None)
```

Next, I would like to convert strings into dates. I tried to use the line:

```
dates2 = dt.datetime.strptime([dates], '"%Y-%m-%d"').date()
```

however, I got an error:

> TypeError: must be string, not list

I figured out that such a code works fine:

```
data1='"2010-02-28"'
data1_1 = dt.datetime.strptime(data1, '"%Y-%m-%d"').date()
```

How should I deal with the described problem?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Note to future readers:** Please do not edit this answer. `'"%Y-%m-%d"'` is not a mistake. OP's dates are surrounded by quotes.

---

`dates` is a list of strings. So if you want to create a list of dates from its elements:

```
dates_list = [dt.datetime.strptime(date, '"%Y-%m-%d"').date() for date in dates]
```

This line iterates over the strings in the `dates` list and using list comprehension to create a new list of dates.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7.3 and I needed to remove the double quotes in order for this to work for me.

Comment: @MichaelSzczepaniak that's because your date strings are not surrounded with double-quotes like OP's.

Comment: @DeepSpace OP stands for ? to make this work I had to remove double-quotes "

Comment: @AnujGupta Original Poster, ie the quesion asker

Comment: What does `dt` refer to in `dt.datetime`? Thanks

Comment: @Confounded the `datetime` module, which is canonically imported as `import datetime as dt`

Answer (score 1):

You can use split for faster result:

```
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d").split('-')
```